# can't upgrade magento to 1.7 from 1.5.1

Tags: magento

Please help!
I have an installation of magento v 1.5.1 and I want to upgrade it to 1.7 but when i try to
list upgrades, this is what i only see:

```
wp_theme_grayscale: 1.0.7 => 1.4.0
RicoNeitzel_VertNav: 0.3.1 => 0.4.0
Locale_Mage_community_fr_FR: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
TBT_Enhancedgrid: 1.3.2.1 => 1.031
```

any suggestions?

after upgrading all,
and tried to list all upgrades again,
it couldn't see any upgrade anymore.

your help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I used this guide. http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/
I did not get any error. the updates above are just the updates that i can see,

Comment: Have you tried `./mage upgrade-all --force` or `./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force`?

Comment: tried that one already, but I just received an error "Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists", after the upgrade using ./mage install http://....... I tried to use the command "find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} /;" and "find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} /;" and after that tried to check my site and now this error appeared. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run

```
./mage list-upgrades
```

In some cases there might be no Mage_* entries in the list. In this case the following command can be used:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Comment: Hi I had tried this option, but I received this error.
Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists

Comment: browser. also right now this is the other error. "Error in file: "/home/rick/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/sql/oauth_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'oauth_consumer' already exists"

Answer (score 3):

OK, I can share my successful experience of upgrading:

1. Go to System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager
2. Log in using your username and password
3. Click on “Check for Upgrades” button

4.You will notice that most package rows turn to yellow. These packages are the only that have available updates. Go to each package row, click on “Actions” drop-down menu and select the most current stable version available.

Note: Stable version available may vary for each package. For example, some packages may have 1.7.0.2 upgrade version and others 1.7.0.1 or lower. Don’t bother with this, just pick the latest stable version available.

1. When you are done selecting upgrade version for all packages, click on “Commit Changes” button.
2. Now, you have to wait. Give it some time. During upgrading process, you may see various notes or outputs that may be tricky and you may think that the process is done. Well, IT IS NOT. Just wait, give it some more minutes. The process will be done when there is no activity in the “command line” like console for about one minute.
3. Click on “Refresh” button. You are almost done! Technically, you have completed the upgrade process.
4. Go to your cPanel file manager or your FTP client and delete EVERYTHING in var/ directory.
5. Last but not least, reindex data in Admin -> Index Management

When you enter admin section and scroll down, you will notice that it says “Magento ver. 1.7.0.2”

This process worked for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. 
what i did is after the upgrade, i re uploaded my database back up, and viola the error is gone. The error has a hint, and yes because of duplicate thing that it could not continue if the table already exist.